# How can I change this so that the outputs on s2 also only show the ones that aren't repeated from s1?

Tags: python, pandas, series

I only want the outputs where s1 and s2 don't match. I have to take out all the data that are both in s1 and s2 and keep only the unique data.
This is my code:

```
for i in range(0,10):
  if s1[i] in s2.values:
    s1 = s1.drop([i])
print('Different values in s1:')
print(s1)
print()
for i in range(0,10):
  if s2[i] in s1.values:
    s2 = s2.drop([i])
print('Different values in s2:')
print(s2)
```

It works for s1, but because the values from s1 are already erased, s2 just shows every single output. How can I change the code so that it works for both?

This is my current outputs for the two pandas series (I used randint() so every time I rerun the code the numbers change, but it should always look something like this):

```
Panda Series 1:
0     3
1     3
2     9
3    10
4     6
5     7
6     2
7     5
8     4
9     9
dtype: int64

Panda Series 2:
0     8
1     9
2     5
3     8
4     8
5    10
6    10
7     8
8    10
9     6
dtype: int64
```

This is my output for the faulty code:

```
Different values in s1:
0    3
1    3
5    7
6    2
8    4
dtype: int64

Different values in s2:
0     8
1     9
2     5
3     8
4     8
5    10
6    10
7     8
8    10
9     6
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Please include input and current (faulty) and expected output.

Comment: Are s1 and s2 two different Pandas Series?

Comment: @AllanWind Just did!

Comment: @AliSultan yup!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would to make a copy of s1 (say, s1a) and update it, then perform the same operation on s2 but use s1 to query the data.  When done set s1 = s1a.

```
s1a = s1
for i in range(0,10):
  if s1a[i] in s2.values:
    s1a = s1a.drop([i])
print('Different values in s1:')
print(s1a)
print()
for i in range(0,10):
  if s2[i] in s1.values:
    s2 = s2.drop([i])
print('Different values in s2:')
print(s2)
s1 = s1a
```

You could also join s1 and s2 with how=inner.  The result would be the intersection you need to remove from both.

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to add something. I need to take out all the data that are in both s1 and s2 and only keep the unique data @AllanWind

Comment: While my suggestion is very close to yours (so it's easy for you to understand), @Serge Ballesta's solution is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You could first identify the values to keep in both Series, and only then drop the unwanted ones:

```
k1 = s1.apply(lambda x: x not in s2.values)
k2 = s2.apply(lambda x: x not in s1.values)
s1 = s1[k1]
s2 = s2[k2]
```

A expected, you get for s1:

```
0    3
1    3
5    7
6    2
8    4
Name: s1, dtype: int64
```

and for s2:

```
0    8
3    8
4    8
7    8
Name: s2, dtype: int64
```